# How can I find/search for an unregistered user?

Tags: discussion, search, unregistered-users

I recall there were three or four unregistered user with the same name on Math.SE. How can I confirm it? Is there anyway to search for the user? If one person is creating more than one unregistered account, is there anything we must do about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I recall there were three or four unregistered user with the same name on Math.SE. How can I confirm it? Is there anyway to search for the user?

As stated in [Is there a way to sift through a list of unregistered users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49764/is-there-a-way-to-sift-through-a-list-of-unregistered-users) and confirmed by @BenBrocka:

> The "Users" tab seems to only indicate registered users.

Google, however, will allow you to see a list of (all?) unregistered users, since their profile pages contain the string `Unregistered less info`.

To do so, you can use [StackExchange Google Search](https://stackapps.com/questions/3182/stackexchange-google-search) (a user script of mine) or this [direct link](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22Unregistered%20less%20info%22%20inurl:math.stackexchange.com/users%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com+-site%3A*.math.stackexchange.com).

> If one person is creating more than one unregistered account, is there anything we must do about it?

I don't think so.

An unregistered user account consist basically of a cookie. If you delete your cookies, go incognito, change your browser, use another computer, format your hard drive, are [inactive for too long](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55523/does-stack-overflow-forget-unregistered-users-after-some-period-of-time), etc., you'll automatically create a new account when you come back.

Thus, forbidding somebody from creating several unregistered accounts means **forcing** that person to register. It's either allowed to use the site without registering or it isn't...

Of course, if there's some kind of foul play (i.e., interaction between the accounts), that something entirely different.

Comment: Confirmed, the users tab seems to ignore unregistered users